# spring project resources import issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I have an interesting issue! In my Spring project, i am trying to import 2 different .js files into my JSP pages. One .js file is working, but another faile with message

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8080/springMoneyProject/resources/script/newscript.js'

These two scriptes are storing in the same directory WebContent/resources/script/

Directoty mapped in config file:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {


      registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
   }
```

Scripts are imported by the same way

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/newscript.js"></script> 
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/moneyCosts.js"></script>
```

What the problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! I got typo in the script name!!